# Wordpress site has a lot of connection

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress

Recently my wordpress site is having troubles and is stopping from working due to heavy load in the mysql processes. I need to know what is causing all this traffic and how to narrow the issue so I can troubleshoot the error. I ran some commands and I am getting this results

```
show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 143   |
| Connections              | 17736 |
| Max_used_connections     | 198   |
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     |
| Threads_connected        | 6     |
+--------------------------+-------+

mysqladmin status
Uptime: 3711  Threads: 3  Questions: 17872313  Slow queries: 13  Opens: 344  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 335  Queries per second avg: 4816.036
```

and sometimes the cpu consumption by mysql reaches the 300%

Comment: This would be a much better question for: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How many users does your site have simultaneously visiting?

Comment: @Merijndk it goes from 400 to 1000. but, the moment I ran those commands it was around 200 (because of the problem I am mentioning)